# Using memcpy() to copy a 4 byte array into a uint32_t and another 4 byte array

Tags: c, memory, endianness, memcpy

I am trying to understand the below observation while using memcpy(),

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[4] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44};
    
    uint32_t cpy;
    memcpy(&cpy, arr, 4);
    printf("%x\n", cpy);
    uint8_t *temp = (uint8_t *)&cpy;
    printf("&cpy[0]=%p, val=%x\n", temp, *temp);
    printf("&cpy[1]=%p, val=%x\n", temp+1, *(temp+1));
    printf("&cpy[2]=%p, val=%x\n", temp+2, *(temp+2));
    printf("&cpy[3]=%p, val=%x\n", temp+3, *(temp+3));
    
    uint8_t cpy2[4];
    memcpy(cpy2, arr, 4);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", cpy2[i]);   
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("&cpy2[0]=%p\n", &cpy2[0]);
    printf("&cpy2[1]=%p\n", &cpy2[1]);
    printf("&cpy2[2]=%p\n", &cpy2[2]);
    printf("&cpy2[3]=%p\n", &cpy2[3]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output I got,

```
44332211
&cpy[0]=0x7ffdc763c020, val=11
&cpy[1]=0x7ffdc763c021, val=22
&cpy[2]=0x7ffdc763c022, val=33
&cpy[3]=0x7ffdc763c023, val=44
11 22 33 44
&cpy2[0]=0x7ffdc763c034
&cpy2[1]=0x7ffdc763c035
&cpy2[2]=0x7ffdc763c036
&cpy2[3]=0x7ffdc763c037
```

Why is the output of the printf statement for the `cpy` variable reversed? Isn't the MSB (0x44) at a higher address than the LSB (0x11), so, shouldn't the output be `11223344`?

Comment: On most machines, the LSB is at a lower address — this is called "little endian".  But in the number `0x44332211`,  `44` is the MSB or most-significant byte, and `11` is the LSB.  See also the Wikipedia article on [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)! The story behind the term is funny, too.

Comment: @SteveSummit Certainly _many_ are _little endian_.  "most machines" today are little embedded ones - billions per year.  I wonder is _most_ really applies.

Comment: Seems you are contradicting yourself here: `Isn't the MSB (0x44) at a higher address`... `so, shouldn't the output be 11223344`. If `0x44` is the MSB, then surely you should expect `44332211`, as you get.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I see. I meant that the MSB in the output is 0x44 but it is at a higher address. I assumed that printf() would print from lower address to higher address and hence was expecting 0x44 to be the LSB.

Comment: In this case `printf()` is printing the value of a `uint32_t` variable - the variable's internal representation is irrelevant in that context. Naturally, `printf()` must logically work the same on little endian and big endian systems.

Comment: Save yourself lots of typing. `typedef union { uint32_t i; uint8_t c[4]; } v_t;` You can define one of these, then `v_t x.i = intVal;` and then work with `x.c[0]`, etc. to examine each byte.

Answer (score 1):

On a little-endian machine such as you're using, multi-byte numbers do indeed seem to be reversed.  When we write a number like `0x44332211` in conventional left-to-right order, we write the most-significant byte (`44`) first, on the left, then proceed to the less-significant bytes: `33`, `22`, and finally the least-significant `11`.

But on a little-endian machine, the least-significant byte is stored first.  Stated another way, if we write

```
uint32_t num = 0x44332211;
uint8_t *p = &num;
```

the pointer `p` points to the byte `0x11`, and pointers past `p` (`p+1`, `p+2`, and `p+3`) point at `22`, `33`, and `44`.

But if we think of memory addresses as increasing from left to right, that means that if we write the bytes in memory order (or if we print them out as an array of `unsigned char`, or do the obvious pointer arithmetic) we see

```
11 22 33 44
```

which is, yes, backwards from `0x44332211`.

Despite its ubiquity, this pattern is easy to forget and often surprising.  It's just something you have to get used to.